# curve of degree $(g-1)$ in $ \mathbb{P}^{g-1}$ ~~ intersects the canonical curve $C =\iota_{K}(S)$ at $(g −1)$ points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let S be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g \ge2$, and $\iota_{K}:S\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{g-1}$ canonical mapping of $S$.

I was reading a text and it was written that: $(1)$ "When $S$ is hyperelliptic, the canonical curve $C =\iota_{K}(S)$ is a non-singular rational 
curve of degree $(g-1)$ in $ \mathbb{P}^{g-1}$"

Then I went to read another reference on this subject, then I found the following: $(2)$"In the hyperelliptic case, a hyperplane $H\in \mathbb({P}^{g-1})^*$
intersects the canonical curve $C =\iota_{K}(S)$  at $(g −1)$ points."

My question is: is there any relation between (1) and (2)???
Both are consequences of $S$ be a hyperelliptic, and both, $(1)$ and $(2)$, are characterized by the number $(g-1)$.

Thank very much

Comment: (2) is weaker than (1), since degree $g-1$ implies a hyperplane intersects it in $g-1$ points. So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is: is there any relation between (1) and (2)???